# How to use checkboxes with Phalcon forms?

Tags: forms, checkbox, phalcon

I am creating a form using [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/en/) that has a checkbox on it. I use this code to create the checkbox in my `PagesForm.php` file

```
$this->add(new Check('usesLayout'));
```

and then in my view I have

```
{{ form.render("usesLayout") }}
```

However, if the checkbox is unchecked then Phalcon complains about `usesLayout is required`.

The `html` code produced by the view is

```
<input type="checkbox" id="usesLayout" name="usesLayout" value="1" checked="checked" />
```

What is the correct way to create a Phalcon form with a checkbox so that it accepts it both checked and unchecked?

**Desired outcome**

After looking back at a form made when using [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) the html output is

```
<input type="hidden" name="usesLayout" id="usesLayout_" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="usesLayout" id="usesLayout" value="1" checked="checked" />
```

This works fine, so I am looking for something similar to this.

**Current Workaround**

After modifying the code in the final response to [this question](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2890) I have this workaround currently (I use this instead of `Phalcon\Forms\Element\Check`)

```
namespace Armaware\InBrowserDev\Forms\Element;

use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Check as PhalconCheck;

class Check extends PhalconCheck
{
    /**
     * Renders the element widget returning html
     *
     * @param array|null $attributes Element attributes
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($attributes = null)
    {
        $attrs = array();

        if (!is_null($attributes)) {
            foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrVal) {
                if (is_numeric($attrName) || in_array($attrName, array('id', 'name', 'placeholder'))) {
                    continue;
                }

                $attrs[] = $attrName .'="'. $attrVal .'"';
            }
        }

        $attrs = ' '. implode(' ', $attrs);

        $id      = $this->getAttribute('id', $this->getName());
        $name    = $this->getName();
        $checked = '';

        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $checked = ' checked';
        }

        return <<<HTML
<input type="hidden" id="{$id}_" name="{$name}" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" id="{$id}" name="{$name}" value="1"{$attrs}{$checked} />
HTML;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> public Phalcon\Forms\ElementInterface setDefault (unknown $value) inherited from Phalcon\Forms\Element
>
> Sets a default value in case the form does not use an entity or there is no value available for the element in _POST

[Source](http://php-phalcon-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Forms_Element_Check.html).

Looks like your declaration of form can look like this:

```
$controls[] = (new Check('usesLayout', ['value' => '1']))
    ->setLabel('Should I use layout?')
    ->setDefault('0') // or `false` in case it's not filtered
    ->addFilter('bool'); // filtering to boolean value
```

Not tested, but probably will do. You can always try to make this trick with handling this in `beforeValidation()` method of form, but have no space to test it right now and am not risking on failurable solution here.